# How to make all Android projects within the same domain be created with the same structure?

Tags: java, android, gradle

I have been researching this topic and have not found any concrete answer on how to do it or if Android Studio allows it to be done. What I intend to do is that all Android projects created from Android Studio within my company's domain come with a structure customized by me. For example, imagine that I implement a login, I want all future projects, when created, to already contain these login files in their structure and can be edited, but the base is there. Is it possible? If yes, how can I do it?

I thank you for your attention and any help.

Best Regards.

Comment: What you want is a base library/ies for your projects.

Comment: Hey, @m0skit0! Do you have any link or tutorial that you can share with me? I need to learn about that.

Comment: https://developer.android.com/studio/projects/android-library

Comment: Note that the point of a library is not to modify it but to extend it.

Comment: Thanks @m0skit0 ! I will try that. For what I see, it always require manual intervention right? I mean, if I create a new project, I need to add this module/library on gradle to get this on my project, right? There is any way to automatize this? Like I create a project and I get the login files without any action?

Comment: So, doing that, I can't modify the code?

Comment: Android Studio has no built-in tool for what you're looking for. You can setup a script to setup everything for you, if that's what you want. You can run it and it will copy the new files and whatnot. I would stick to the standard way of doing it though, the way you are thinking about modifying the base code is flawed: you will need to keep track of so many changes on each project, etc... It is better to use OOP features for that instead of modifying the code, e.g. inheritance.  Nobody does this, there's a reason for it. But feel free to try it by yourself :)

Comment: Thanks for your feedback @m0skit0, that was really important

Comment: @m0skit0 In my specific case, I don't really need to modify a bunch of files. Probably I will only need to change the layout files and it will only happen in rare cases. So, forget about the need of modifying the files. I just want to everytime someone inside of my domain create a new project in android studio, it will get the structure files for login for example. I understood this only can be done with a script, but I think it will not be so flawed for this case, right? I am not sure how to do the script too, do you have any idea or suggestion?

Comment: Then you just need to import a couple of modules, I don't think it's work that requires scripting, it's basically 2 lines in the build.gradle. As an alternative you can have a base project you can copy and use (or better, a branch in git).

Comment: @m0skit0 thanks mate! :)